# Copy constructor deleted error. Compiler is not calling the move assignment operator

Tags: c++

Here's an MRE.

```
struct SDL_Renderer {};
struct Renderer
{
    Renderer(SDL_Renderer* renderer) : pRenderer{ renderer } {}

    Renderer& operator=(Renderer&& other)
    {
        pRenderer = other.pRenderer;
        other.pRenderer = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* pRenderer;
};

int main()
{
    SDL_Renderer sdlRenderer;
    Renderer renderer = Renderer{ &sdlRenderer };

    //Error: Copy constructor is a deleted function
    Renderer moved = std::move(renderer);
}
```

Why the compiler not calling the move assignment operator instead of complaining that a copy constructor is missing. I am not even trying to copy anything. Am I?

Comment: *I am not even trying to copy anything. Am I?*  Yes the code is trying to copy something: `Renderer moved = std::move(renderer);`

Comment: Assignment is when you modify an **existing object**. Constructors are for creating a **new object**. No, what does the line where you get an error doing? Is `moved` an existing object, or a brand new one getting declared?

Comment: Just add this move-constructor: `Renderer(Renderer&& other) : pRenderer{std::exchange(other.pRenderer, nullptr)} { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Renderer moved = std::move(renderer)`

This syntax looks like an assignment but since `moved` is being created it's actually equivalent to `Renderer moved(std::move(renderer));`.

In order to use the assignment operator you should use it **after** `moved` is instantiated.

```
Renderer moved(nullptr);
moved = std::move(renderer);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the compiler not calling the move assignment operator instead of complaining that a copy constructor is missing.

Because you are not performing a (move) assignment operation to begin with, so the (move) assignment operator is not called.

A statement like `Type ident = value;` is initialization, not assignment.  It is largely just syntax sugar for `Type ident(value);` hence no assignment operator is called.

So, in this case:

```cpp
Renderer renderer = Renderer{ &sdlRenderer };
```

Prior to C++17, this is the same as the following, which creates a temporary `Renderer` object and then copy-constructs the `renderer` object since no move constructor is defined for `Renderer`:

```cpp
Renderer renderer{ Renderer{ &sdlRenderer } };
```

However, since C++17, the compiler optimizes away the temporary object, so it is the same as the following instead, which matches the `Renderer(SDL_Renderer*)` constructor that you have defined:

```cpp
Renderer renderer{ &sdlRenderer };
```

Whereas in this case:

```cpp
Renderer moved = std::move(renderer);
```

This the same as the following in all versions:

```
Renderer moved(std::move(renderer));
```

Which is a copy operation when there is no move constructor defined.

Comment: I believe pre C++17 **may** elide the constructors too but C++17 made elision mandatory in some cases.

Comment: This is a more complete answer. Let me know if you think I should delete mine.